# Why does invoking a method with a short choose the `void (int)` overload over `void (Short)`?

Tags: java, overloading, boxing

I am learning Java.  When I call `go(x)`, I get ‘int’.  Why not ‘Short’?

```
public class test {
    public static void go(Short n) {System.out.println("Short");}
    public static void go(int n) {System.out.println("int");}
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        short x=11;
        go(x);
    }
}
```

Comment: `Short` and `short` are different types.  Try declaring `go` as `go(short n)`.

Comment: The rules for resolving overload calls are complicated.  But basically, when you have a `go` call with a `short` argument, the `go(int)` method is closer than the `go(Short)` method.   Technically, `short` is a subtype of `int` but not `Short`.  And that means that `go(int)` is *more specific* than `go(Short)` ... and that is why it is chosen.

Comment: because widening of type is higher on the priority list than auto-boxing.

Comment: Are you intentionally use `Short` as in the [`java.lang.Short`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Short.html) wrapper class or was it just a typo and you wanted to write the primitive type `short`?

Comment: Why do you *have* an overload `method(Short)`? Don't do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you make a call to an overloaded method, the compiler needs to decide *statically* which of the overloads will be called.  Intuitively, this is done by looking at each of the overloads' signatures, and working out which one is the best match ... based on the *static* types of the argument expressions.  If there is a tie (i.e. no single "best" match), the compiler gives an error saying that the method call is ambiguous.

This is the code of your example.

```
public class test {
    public static void go(Short n) {System.out.println("Short");}
    public static void go(int n) {System.out.println("int");}
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        short x=11;
        go(x);
    }
}
```

The reason that this prints "int" rather than "Short" is because `go(int)` is deemed to be a better match than `go(Short)` to a call where the argument expression's static type is `short`.

(Technically, `short` is a subtype of `int`, but not of `Short`.)

If we change your code to this:

```
public class test {
    public static void go(short n) {System.out.println("short");}
    public static void go(int n) {System.out.println("int");}
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        short x=11;
        go(x);
    }
}
```

we will now see that `short` is printed.   The type `short` is a subtype<sup>1</sup> of both `short` and `int`, but `go(short)` is a closer match than `go(int)`.

The relevant section of the Java Language Specification is [JLS 15.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12).   But beware that is long and complicated ... and NOT recommended for beginners to try to read.  (Indeed, I would posit that *most* Java programmers don't fully understand all of what it says.  Myself included!)

---

<sup>1 - This is according to the definition of subtype used in the JLS.</sup>

Comment: Amen to that last paragraph.  I’ve been writing Java code since 1.0 came out in 1996, and I still find those intricate sections of the JLS truly daunting.

Comment: They are. You can [tag:language-lawyer] all day long about the meaning, happens-before, if a type should be inferred...

Comment: @JohannesKuhn - That is true.  However, there is also a need for documents like the JLS ... to allow those people who **need** to know to understand how the language is supposed to work.  And in the case of *happens-before* ... there is a scarily large number of programmers who *try* to implement multi-threaded applications with nothing more than `volatile`, `synchronized` and `wait / notify`.  And then get obsessed with "lock free" algorithms.  For those people, understanding *happens-before* is essential.